# Can't show my array data after inserting some data in it using firebase and angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I am having a little problem, I will explain after what I want to achieve,this is my html code :

```
<section id="posts">
<div *ngFor="let post of pubs | async; let i = index"   class="publication">
    <app-post (addCmnt)="addCommentaire($event,i)" [text]="post.text" [poster]="{'name':post.poster.name,'image':post.poster.image}"
              [date]="post.date" [comments]="post.comments | json" [show]="post.show" [showComment]="post.showComment"
              [isLiked]="post.isLiked" [numberLikes]="post.numberLikes" [isCommented]="" [photo]="post.photo">
    </app-post>
    {{post.comments}}
</div>
</section>
```

All what is needed in this code is the method addCommentaire and 'post.comments'.
And here is my app.component.ts :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

pubs: Observable <any[]>;
publis:AngularFireList<any>;

constructor(private db?:AngularFireDatabase) {
}

addCommentaire(val, index){
   console.log(val+ "-- msg-- "+ index)
   let i = index+1;
   this.db.list('/posts/'+i+'/comments').push(val);
}
ngOnInit(){
   this.pubs = this.getPosts('/posts');
}

getPosts(path):Observable<any[]> {
   return this.db.list(path).valueChanges();
}

}
```

So I write a comment and it will be added to the database, I get my comment perfectly and it is inserted perfectly, but I can see it inserted in the database but not shown in my view and getting this error :

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' 
of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

Knowing that my code was working fine before updating my database, And when I try this :

```
{{post.comments | json}}
```

I get the expected results, the old ones and the new ones ( the inserted ) like this :

```
{ 
  "1": 
  { "commentator": "Kitsu Ryouta", "content": "Belle cherie chery",
    "pic":"assets/images/Kitsu.jpg" },

  "2": { "commentator": "Abir Khalladi", "content": "Hahahh Merci cutie cutie", 
    "pic": "assets/images/abir.jpg" },

  "3": { "commentator": "Kitsu Ryouta", "content": "De rien :p",
    "pic": "assets/images/Kitsu.jpg" },

  "4": { "commentator": "Taoufiq Benallah", "content": "hh",
    "pic": "assets/images/abir.jpg" },

  "-L5ViAL5EdgWn-mBtCb-": { "commentator": "Taoufiq BENALLAH",
    "content": "k", "pic": "assets/images/taoufiq.jpg" }
}
```

But when I remone the ' | json ' I get only this :

```
[object Object]
```

despite the fact that I am having 5 objects in my array ..

I hope you understood my problem, and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *ngFor on an Object but only on an Array

```
{ 
  "1": 
  { "commentator": "Kitsu Ryouta", "content": "Belle cherie chery",
    "pic":"assets/images/Kitsu.jpg" },

  "2": { "commentator": "Abir Khalladi", "content": "Hahahh Merci cutie cutie", 
    "pic": "assets/images/abir.jpg" },

  "3": { "commentator": "Kitsu Ryouta", "content": "De rien :p",
    "pic": "assets/images/Kitsu.jpg" },

  "4": { "commentator": "Taoufiq Benallah", "content": "hh",
    "pic": "assets/images/abir.jpg" },

  "-L5ViAL5EdgWn-mBtCb-": { "commentator": "Taoufiq BENALLAH",
    "content": "k", "pic": "assets/images/taoufiq.jpg" }
}
```

So it's not an Array or an Iterable.

You should have a data like this :

```
[{ 
  { "commentator": "Kitsu Ryouta", "content": "Belle cherie chery",
    "pic":"assets/images/Kitsu.jpg" },
{ "commentator": "Abir Khalladi", "content": "Hahahh Merci cutie cutie", 
    "pic": "assets/images/abir.jpg" },
{ "commentator": "Kitsu Ryouta", "content": "De rien :p",
    "pic": "assets/images/Kitsu.jpg" },
{ "commentator": "Taoufiq Benallah", "content": "hh",
    "pic": "assets/images/abir.jpg" },
{ "commentator": "Taoufiq BENALLAH",
    "content": "k", "pic": "assets/images/taoufiq.jpg" }
}]
```

Pipe json is to show an object like a string. If you don't use it on an object, you always see :

`[object Object]`

Comment: Well, Thank you for the answer, but the solution is ?

Comment: The solution is to change data structure of post.comments from Object to Array.